# How to enable internet banking payment method for my PayPal sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented paypal payment gateway for my application on sandbox mode. Now I can use paypal account payment and direct payment such as credit card/debit card payment.

[image]

But now I want to pay by using internet banking. How can I enable this feature for my sandbox merchant account?

Comment: Are you referring to giropay?

Comment: What do you mean, as in offer payment by online banking? You will have to use a different service.

Comment: can you please tel me how did you do this?

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK I've implemented this but am not able to accept credit or debit card directly without PayPal login.PayPal documentation says to create PayPal button .is that what I've to do?

Answer (score -3):

To make paypal payment using net banking use this website's steps:

http://paypalpaymentusingnetbanking.in/

The charge is also nominal @ 3%.